# SupportMapFragment getView().findViewById(0x1) is null

Tags: android, google-maps

why does this return a null when  mMapFragment is not null?

```
View zoom = mMapFragment.getView().findViewById(0x1);
```

I need to move the zoom button to the apposite side

```
   if (zoom != null && zoom.getLayoutParams() instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
        // ZoomControl is inside of RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) zoom.getLayoutParams();
        // Align it to - parent BOTTOM|LEFT
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);

        // Update margins, set to 10dp
        final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);

        zoom.setLayoutParams(params);
      }
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know the id is 0x1?  I've never seen examples, tutorials, or anything where the id number is actually known in advance.  I thought they were assigned at compile time.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Why you set Static id ???

Comment: I was following this one http://blog.kozaxinan.com/2013/08/how-to-change-position-of.html

Comment: you should rather use the `id` value placed in your `xml` file where you have put your support map fragment.

Comment: The author of that article states, "But this is not a good solution but it works for me. On the otherhand it can be change every new build of google play service. Do a lot of test before implement this." The Google Play Service has been updated in the last year (when that was written), so... maybe try checking out the other links on the page?

Comment: ok. ill try other solution

Answer (score 0):

Use GoogleMap and MapView instead of SupportMapFragment:

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

Java onCreateView function:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapaPrincipal);
GoogleMap map = mapView.getMap();
```

note: You can define "mapView" and "map" as global variables and use it in all functions after they are initialized  in onCreateView()